# Windows Explorer does not receive WM_DESTROY. How can I detect when the user closes their explorer window?

Tags: winapi, hook, windows-explorer, setwindowshookex

I'm writing a program which needs to detect when windows are closed. Currently I am using SetWindowsHookEx to register a hook which can monitor window messages.

I am monitoring for WM_DESTROY events to find out when windows have been destroyed. This works fine for most windows with Windows Explorer being a notable exception. Windows Explorer does not appear to receive a WM_DESTROY event when it terminates (but receives most other interesting events).

Is there a reason why Windows Explorer does not receive WM_DESTROY?

More importantly, is there a alternate method I can use to detect when Windows Explorer terminates other than listening for WM_DESTROY?

Thanks!

I am using Windows 7 (not sure how relevant this information is)

Comment: Pretty hard to create a constructive answer for this question.  Sure, WM_DESTROY *normally* is sent when a window is destroyed.  But window destruction doesn't have to be normal.  Nothing is sent when Windows destroys a window when the process terminates for example.  And there's just nothing normal about Explorer, 18 years of appcompat hacks to keep popular shell extensions running saw to that.  And the extra special option that Explorer has, the "Run window in its own process" option.  Plenty of stuff to conspire making your code ineffective.

Comment: So does that means that I can't rely on WM_DESTROY messages in general? Do I really have to resort to doing something like polling EnumWindows at regular intervals and checking which windows are no longer there?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`WH_CBT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977.aspx) hook instead of a message hook, and have it handle `HCBT_DESTROYWND` notifications.

Comment: I just tried this and it did not work. As with WM_DESTROY, I receive HCBT_DESTROYWND notifications from other windows, but none from Windows Explorer.

Comment: Then the window is not being destroyed. It is likely just being hidden for later re-use by the same explorer.exe process. Opening a new Windows Explorer window does not always start a new explorer.exe process.